# What is the "next-line" rule at TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rule, tslint

I could not find code examples for the following situation:

```
"next-line": [
  true,
  "check-catch",
  "check-finally",
  "check-else",
  "check-open-brace",
  "check-whitespace"
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a next-line, I think the equivalent is one-line:

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/one-line/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `next-line` rule part of core TSLint, but there is [a `one-line` rule](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/one-line/). The documentation isn't great, but it generally enforces a more compact way of placing braces and keywords.

For example, these are good:

```
class My Class {
 // ...
}

if (true) {
 // ...
} else {
 // ...
}
```

whereas this would be bad:

```
class MyClass
{
 // ...
}

if (true){
 // missing whitespace above
}
else
{
  // else is on the wrong line and the brace is also
}
```

Comment: in our tslint.json were the both of them `one-line` and `next-line`, must be a mistake,..